# how to start with ruby and install it? Which is better windows or VM?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ruby-install

I have Windows 8 OS running on my machine and i also have Linux Ubuntu Virtual machine. I want to install ruby and work with it and I heard that windows doesn't support all ruby gems and Linux will be better for ruby. so do you think I should install ruby on windows or on my Virtual machine? which will be better? And help me with installing ruby on it. Also I want to know if there is any IDE as in eclipse for java better than a command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You may have some problems with gems on Windows, but in general those will be the gems that support Linux-only functionality. The same applies to a Linux installation: you may have problems with some gems there too, in particular with those that support Windows-only functionality.

Unlike Perl, where Windows compatability was bolted on after the language had established itself on Linux, Ruby is genuinely a cross-platform language, and there is no *best choice* of platform. Your only consideration should be, *"what platform do I want to develop for?"*

Answer (score 0):

You may have some problems with gems on windows. Although they are mostly solveable, you'd better install x86 ruby interpreter.

- First thing you should do is install ruby and devkit from [this site](http://rubyinstaller.org/). Full information about install process you may find [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki).
- Well, you almost done. I think you will need some [gems](http://rubygems.org/).
- IDE is a hard question. I heard you mentioned eclipse. It is not only for java!:) If you are interested you may keep using eclipse. How? Read [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/). It's about DLTK (Dynamic Languages Toolkit). But my choice is  [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails). It is eclipse based IDE.
  Why Aptana? It is free and provides eclipse-like user interface. 
  If you want to use debugger (I know you do) you should install *debug-base* and *debug-ide* gems.

  There are also some proprietary IDEs like [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) (i really like it btw) or VS "plugin" [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/)

> I have windows8, ruby 2.0 x86, Aptana IDE. Not everything but almost works fine.:)

Good luck!